# ECMAScript 6 loop 'for-of' in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

It looks like a problem with ECMAScript 6 loop 'for-of' in Microsoft Edge.
In fact, when i loop with a [key, value] pair, Edge return this error : SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier

For example with the code below :

```js
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, 'zero');
myMap.set(1, 'one');
    
for (var [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
```

The part of code is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Iterating_Maps_with_for..of

And i use Edge 25.10586.0.0 to test it.

Any idea?

Comment: first of all, which version of edge you're using?

Comment: wait, what's a myMap?)

Comment: Seems to work fine in Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cu1gfgy6/

Comment: @havenchyk: Probably a `Map` instance?

Comment: We are getting this : "Uncaught ReferenceError: myMap is not defined" This needs to be solved first.

Comment: @Ryan yep, but maybe Immutable Map?

Comment: Anyway, seems likely that you’re using Edge 13, which doesn’t support destructuring.

Comment: btw `.entries()` is unnecessary

Comment: @aaaaaa - It depends upon what type of object `myMap` is and what its default iterator does.  Your comment is correct if it is a `Map` object, but not if it is an array, for example.

Comment: @jfriend00 - we could go all day discussing the things we don't know as fact from any given OP.  At some point you just have to assume what's most likely, and my money's on `myMap instanceof Map`

Comment: @aaaaaa - My point was that your comment is not generically true all the time.  You were guessing what `myMap` was and did not state that in your comment.  I've voted to close this question since it does not contain enough information to answer and the OP appears to be nowhere to be found.

Comment: guessing?  haha okay I'll leave this alone

Comment: @aaaaaa - Please join my in voting to close this question since it does not contain enough info to answer.

Comment: Hello, 

@havenchyk my version of Edge is : 25.10586.0.0 and myMap is a map object : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn263029(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: What is curious is it work perfectly on chrome and firefox.

Comment: Hello, @jfriend00 - the question has not enouth info because it is a generic question of ES6/javascript compatibility with Edge and effectively i found that [key, value] pair in the loop return an error in edge. i'll answer myself. thx

Comment: The point was that if this was a really good question (that indicated what type of data `myMap` was and what version of the browser you were running) you would have gotten a crisp answer in about 10 minutes.  Instead, you left us to guess here for 17 hours.  That's not how to write a good question here and is not a good way for you to get a quick answer and is not efficient for the community of people who provide answers.  You can do a lot better which is what I'm trying to teach you.

Comment: And, if you checked back here several times in the first hour after posting, this could have all been cleared up very quickly and you'd have an answer much quicker and we would not spend so much time debating what you might have meant by your incomplete question.  Next time, please try to put more relevant info in the question AND please check back several times in the first hour after posting.  You will get a faster answer and avoid downvotes and close votes for a question that is missing information and you will be a better contributing citizen in this community.

Comment: And, even now, you've still failed to edit your question to include the proper information that people asked for almost a day ago to make it a useful reference question for the future.  That is why your question is about to get closed (it already has 3 votes to close it).  stackoverflow is not like a typical online forum where you can post anything and not be responsive to questions.  It works differently.  We clean up questions (by closing them) that don't follow the posting rules, aren't clear and when the OP is not responsive to questions.

Comment: Your question is not a generic ES6 question at all.  I gave you an exact jsFiddle that works absolutely perfectly in Edge with your exact code.  It's up to you to show us why your code isn't working just like that.  It's not up to us to guess what might be different in your circumstance.  Here, the burden is on you to explain the question to us, not on us to guess what you might be doing.

Comment: Sorry @jfriend00 I'm not useds to using stackoverflow yet and i thank it was a simple and known problem. 
Sorry and thank you for your remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [key, value] pair in the loop return an error in old version of Microsoft Edge (<= 25.10586).
It needs to use an array instead like this :

```js
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, 'zero');
myMap.set(1, 'one');

for(var pair of myMap.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine in Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 as my jsFiddle (posted 16 hours ago) shows.  So, either you are doing something different in your read code or you have an older version of Edge.  This is not a generic Edge or ES6 problem.

Comment: Yes it seems it's really a problem with my version of Edge (25.10586.0.0)